# Applying application-level signing in HTTP

Tags: hash, http, request-signing

I have to secure HTTP requests`s body on application layer, so I wanted to generate signatures with hash of body and the receiver will validate it.

But I can do it in different way and apply it into existing architecture. My server already signs responses's body, so I can apply into this signature the hash of request's body the server received.

At the moment of sending request the client should generate hash for body and store it. When get's response, should verify whether received request hash is equal to stored request hash.

I've never seen similar solution so I worry about security. Is it safe? Does it make some attacks possible that are not possible with first approach?

Comment: This feels very XY problem, perhaps you should explain the need to "secure" the request body instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches serve two entirely different purposes. If you're not sure which one want, then you should first define what you're trying to *achieve* and then choose the right approach accordingly.

If the client signs their request, then the server is able to verify that the request it receives has in fact been produced by the client at some point and not been altered since. Note that the server doesn't know if the request has actually been *sent* by the client and was meant to be sent at this time. An attacker can replay old requests (unless you include a nonce), change the order within a sequence of requests (unless you include a counter) or only send a partial sequence with some requests missing (unless you include a counter)

If the server signs their response and includes a hash of the request, the client can verify:

- that the response has actually been produced by the server at some point and not been altered since
- that the response is referring to a particular request

Note that the server cannot verify anything here. It's possible that it's processing a completely bogus request, and this will only be detected when the client receives the response -- when it may already be too late. Also note that the problem of replay exists here as well.

Which approach you choose depends on your requirements. Maybe you need exactly one of the two, maybe a combination of both, maybe none.

In any case, I would strongly recommend you use an existing protocol rather than trying to invent your own. It's very easy to make a subtle design mistake somewhere which completely defeats the purpose of the entire protocol.